# How to call program written in c++ call my DLL written in c

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012, dll, dev-c++

I have developped a dll in C and I have called in my C++ program with this method

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#include "mydll.h"
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct myown_struct *ss = NULL;
    int i = 0,j = 0, result = 0;
    struct myown_struct2 *s = NULL;
    myfunction("string1", "string2", "string3", 1500);
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

mydll.h :

```
#ifndef _DLL_H_
#define _DLL_H_

#if BUILDING_DLL
# define DLLIMPORT __declspec (dllexport)
#else /* Not BUILDING_DLL */
# define DLLIMPORT __declspec (dllimport)
#endif /* Not BUILDING_DLL */

struct myown_struct {
  int fd;
  char buf[32];
  unsigned int len;
} __attribute__((packed));

DLLIMPORT void myfunction(char *s1, char* s2, char *s3, int n);

#endif /* _DLL_H_ */
```

I get this error :

C:\Users\user01\Desktop\test\main.cpp In function `int main(int, char**)`
 C:\Users\user01\Desktop\test\main.cpp `myfunction' undeclared (first use this function)`

How can I fix it?

Comment: Show us mydll.h? It would seem that either your usage does not match the signature in the header or it is not declared in the header.

Comment: @crashmstr: you can see my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your header file `mydll.h` appears to be missing the declaration of `myfunction`. Correct that omission and your code will compile.

On top of that you will need to ensure that:

- The .lib import library that was created when you compiled the DLL is passed to the linker when you link your C++ program.
- The DLL can be found when you attempt to run your program. That is best achieved by placing the DLL in the same directory as the executable.

I would also comment that I would expect to see the `extern "C"` in the header file rather than forcing every single user of the header file to write `extern "C"`. The header file really should stand alone.

Comment: I don't miss declaration of `myfunction` in `mydll.h`

Comment: If that is true, then your compiler is broken. Perhaps you could should your header file.

Comment: I compiled with dev-c++ and visual studio 2012 and I get the same problem

Comment: The code compiles here. When I add the missing include of windows.h. Did you by any chance define `_DLL_H_`?

Comment: Well, the code compiles here. Clearly there is something else at play. Ask yourself why the compiler cannot see a declaration for `myfunction`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49587/discussion-between-linuxcdeveloper-and-david-heffernan)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using VC++, you can use already existing API's for the same

```
typedef void (*myfunction)(char *buf1, char *buf2,char *buf3,char *buf4);
HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(_T("mydll.dll"));
if(hModule!=NULL)
    myfunction GetMyFunction = (myfunction) GetProcAddress(hModule,"myfunction");
```

Now use `GetMyFunction()`

Hope this will help

Comment: While this can work, I don't see any reason to use run-time loading of the DLL for this.

Comment: Hey @crashmstr.. can you please tell me the other way which doesnt require loading of dll in runtime... :-)

Comment: @HadeS Load time linking.

Comment: @HadeS You include the header files and call the functions normally. The only other step is to add the `.lib` file generated from the build of the DLL to the linkage. Then it just works.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan for load time linking .lib file need to be used...I guess... :-)

Comment: @HadeS That is correct. It's a cleaner and simpler way to link. I think it is bad that you suggest using the much messier and worse linking approach without actually tackling the real problem. It's best to solve problems the right way.

Comment: Yes, you need the .lib file. But the OP has a *compile* issue which means it has something to do with the header file.

Comment: A downvote does not mean that your answer is wrong. The hint associated with the downvote triangle says "This answer is not useful" . In my opinion, whoever downvoted was correct. This answer is not useful. It is misleading at best.

Comment: linuxcdeveloper's "C" dll might have been built separately from his current "C++" project, and for whatever reason its source and any .lib file is no longer available.  In this is the case, HadeS' answer is the only one that helps.  Until linuxcdeveloper shares more info, it is unreasonable to condemn what is likely the only solution. The failing mydll.h might have been cobbled together recently to be used with an existing, but functional dll. @HadeS LoadLibrary takes a .dll file, not a .h -- fix it.  Your answer might be the best one, given we have so little information about OP's situation.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles...thanks for pointing that ... corrected my answer.. :-)

Comment: @ChristopherOicles actually, if he can't compile when including the header, no, this is not a solution to the problem. If it was a *linker* error, then sure, it makes some sense as an answer.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles That's just silly. He said he is compiling the DLL. Clearly he has the .lib file.

Comment: @David Heffernan He said he has "developped a dll in C" -- not super conclusive that this is contemporary with the C++ project. Also, his tags include both MSVC and DevC++ -- if he made the dll with DevC++, would he even get a .lib which is compatible with the MS Linker?

Comment: @ChristopherOicles Whatever. I suppose you are welcome to your preference of runtime linking.

Comment: @crashmstr I was trying to point out that the dll's .h file may not have been the one originally used when building the dll, that it may have been newly (and erroneously) created as a part of the separate C++ project.

Comment: @David Heffernan Hey! I'm not saying I prefer run-time dynamic linking, just that it might be the only option available in this case. Lol!

Comment: @ChristopherOicles Even if it was (and it surely isn't) then that should be stated in the answer. Otherwise the answer gives the impression that run time linking is the solution to the problem. Which it is not because the problem is a compilation problem and not a link problem. As I'm sure you will agree.

Comment: @David Heffernan Even though the question is tagged with two compilers, two languages, using a dynamic library instead of a static one, you can be "sure" that his fundamental problem is just a screwed up multipart MSVC project?  This is sophistry, bucause I know you're smarter than to believe that.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles All I am sure of is that the reported error indicates that the compiler has not encountered a declaration for `myfunction`.